# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php (line 179) in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Hello I am facing **NotFoundHttpException** error when i access ***/login*** or ***/register***
when i run the php artisan make:auth command, routes are also created their, but ***/login*** or ***/register*** is not working for me, let me share my code with you.

**Web.php**

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

when i check my browers concole its showing this error

> GET http://localhost/laravel5authprc/login 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to access `http://localhost/laravel5authprc/index.php/login`
If it works, then you need to set up a virtual Host in your apache vHosts file

Comment: this is working can you please explain me this lit bit, i am new in laravel ?

Comment: Yes sure! the thing is, when you call http://localhost/laravel5authprc/ without a virtual host, it will only enter the project content, then you manually go to public folder by doing that, laravel executes the index.php file and launch the application. because otherwise it will consider that the root folder is http://localhost/laravel5authprc/ but in reality it is http://localhost/laravel5authprc/public, so to fix it you have to tell your webserver (Apache) to go to http://localhost/laravel5authprc/public when you enter http://localhost/laravel5authprc/ folder, hope its clear now

Comment: if it did work @UmairMehmoodKhanLodhi then you can upvote and select the answer, thanks

Comment: thanks for explanation, i really appreciate your help. i am trying for thumbs up but its showing something is reputation is less then 15.

Comment: I will help you out, I will give u some points, you have now 19, you can click on the check mark to select the answer

Answer (score 0):

Probably something is **NotFoundHttp**...

I'd recommend:

Try:

```
Route::group([ 'prefix' => 'laravel5authprc' ], function () {

Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home.alias');


});
```

Comment: same answer is below, this is not the problem, with what you wrote he will get the URL like: localhost/laravel5authprc/laravel5authprc/login...

Comment: Its also working `Route::group([ 'prefix' => 'laravel5authprc' ], function () {
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home.alias');
});` can you please explain me lit bit this because i am new to laravel ?